# FTP getting 550 Permission denied Apache Ubuntu Server 11

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ftp

I just set up FTP today, and I am getting a 550 Permission denied error.
I tried chmod-ing the directory(/var/www/site1).
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set up the ftp users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Check if your username and password is correct and port number.

the other reason can be you may not be having the permission to use the ftp in your network.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error message transferring files from the server to my laptop. I changed the firewall settings to allow the server IP address. The error no longer appears.
  In my case changing the chmod permissions did not affect it.